# Get the value in an input text box

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, textinput, html-input

What are the ways to get and render an input value using jQuery?

Here is one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txt_name").keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_name" />
```

Comment: use this code: var value=$('#txt_Name').val(); You can also set the value using jquery. please look at this post at: http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-setget-textbox-value-using.html

Answer (score 1840, accepted):

```
//Get
var bla = $('#txt_name').val();

//Set
$('#txt_name').val(bla);
```

Answer (score 620):

You can only select a value with the following two ways:

```
// First way to get a value
value = $("#txt_name").val(); 

// Second way to get a value
value = $("#txt_name").attr('value');
```

If you want to use straight JavaScript to get the value, here is how:

```
document.getElementById('txt_name').value
```

Answer (score 95):

There is one important thing to mention:

```
$("#txt_name").val();
```

will return the current real value of a text field, for example if the user typed something there after a page load.

But:

```
$("#txt_name").attr('value')
```

will return value from DOM/HTML.

Answer (score 45):

You can get the `value` attribute directly since you know it's an `<input>` element, but your current usage of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is already the current one.

For the above, just use `.value` on the DOM element directly, [like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uA2we/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt_name").keyup(function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 24):

You have to use various ways to get current value of an input element.

**METHOD - 1**

If you want to use a simple `.val()`, try this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" />
```

***Get values from Input***

```
// use to select with DOM element.
$("input").val();

// use the id to select the element.
$("#txt_name").val();

// use type="text" with input to select the element
$("input:text").val();
```

***Set value to Input***

```
// use to add "text content" to the DOM element.
$("input").val("text content");

// use the id to add "text content" to the element.
$("#txt_name").val("text content");

// use type="text" with input to add "text content" to the element
$("input:text").val("text content");
```

**METHOD - 2**

Use `.attr()` to get the content.

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" value="" />
```

I just add one attribute to the input field. `value=""` attribute is the one who carry the text content that we entered in input field.

```
$("input").attr("value");
```

**METHOD - 3**

you can use this one directly on your `input` element.

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 16):

I think this function is missed here in previous answers:

```
.val( function(index, value) )
```

Answer (score 15):

You can get the value like this:

```
this['inputname'].value
```

Where `this` refers to the form that contains the input.

Answer (score 10):

To get the textbox value, you can use the jQuery `val()` function.

For example,

`$('input:textbox').val()` – Get textbox value.

`$('input:textbox').val("new text message")` – Set the textbox value.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply set the value in text box.

First, you get the value like

```
var getValue = $('#txt_name').val();
```

After getting a value set in input like

```
$('#txt_name').val(getValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who just like me are newbies in JS and getting `undefined` instead of text value **make sure that your `id` doesn't contain invalid characters**.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will work for sure.

```
var userInput = $('#txt_name').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let quantity = $('input[name = quantity]').val()
```

where the name of the input field is quantity

Answer (score -1):

## Shortest

```
txt_name.value
```

```js
txt_name.onkeyup = e=> alert(txt_name.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_name" />
```