# Javascript keypress event and e.keycode

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keypress, keycode

1. I have a code which is suppose to update the number of *remaining characters left* when the user types in a `text input`. The code is triggered using `keypress` event. The problem is the code is *triggered* only after *2* `keypress`. Why does that happen?
2. I have a code to show the key of **ASCII** code but the character always shows **8** and shows when I press *backspace*. And how to use `String.fromCharCode(event.keycode} ;` method.
3. Why is a `event` parameter added to a `function` ?
   How does `e.keycode` know it is displaying the `keycode` of the *user's* input.

**Code Sample**

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
  <h1>List King</h1>
  <form id="messageForm">
    <h2>My profile</h2>
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <div id="charactersLeft">180 characters</div>
    <div id="lastKey"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var el;                                                    // Declare variables

function charCount(e) {                                    // Declare function
  var textEntered, charDisplay, counter, lastkey;          // Declare variables
  textEntered = document.getElementById('message').value;  // User's text
  charDisplay = document.getElementById('charactersLeft'); // Counter element
  counter = (180 - (textEntered.length));                  // Num of chars left
  charDisplay.textContent = counter;                       // Show chars left

  lastkey = document.getElementById('lastKey');            // Get last key used
  lastkey.textContent = 'Last key in ASCII code: ' + e.keyCode; // Create msg 
}

el = document.getElementById('message');                   // Get msg element
el.addEventListener('keypress', charCount, false);         // keypress -call charCount()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `keypress` event is triggered before the input's value is updated, this is why the counter is not up to date. I'd suggest to listen to the `input` event if you don't need the keyCode. You can also listen to `keyup` (but the update won't be straight forward) or the combination of `keypress` and `keyup` (from "[How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)", I updated the right answer's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/975/)).
2. - Actually, the `keypress` event doesn't seem to be triggered when you press backspace. That been said, an other solution to ignore "muted" keys ("backspace", "shift", "command" and so on) is to listen to the "input" event (but you won't have access to `event.keyCode`). Otherwise you can also ignore your code when the keyCode is not relevant.
   - In regard to [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), simply use `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` to get the keyCode's "human" equivalent.
3. The [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) passed to the function is an object containing all the informations about this given event, including the pressed key.

Comment: 1st question is not by a problem,it works with `keyup` do you have a particular reason.Dont say it comes from somewhere else,show it in your code.@gabin

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj1pj18o/). Open your console and type in the input. As you'll see, `keypress` is triggered every time you press a key.

Comment: I type a character it doesn't fire and next character I type it fires.In the sense I type a 1 character nothing happens next I type another character (so I have typed  2 characters)after I type in my 2nd char the event fires  and shows ( _180-1character_) 179 characters instead of 178 chars left.

Comment: Actually the keypress event triggers before the input's value is updated. I'd suggest to listen to the "input" event if you don't need the keyCode. Otherwise you can listen to "keyup" but the update won't be "straight forward". There's also an other solution from "[How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)" (I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/975/) for your needs).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mpp522L5/ssss ASCII code doesn't update to letters please say whats wromg

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work as expected. I see "a" when I press "a" and "b" when I press "b". Note that some keys don't have readable equivalents (shift, command, ...). What's your browser? And version?

Comment: Latest version of mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use 'keyup' insted of 'keypress'.

2)    lastkey.textContent = 'Last key in ASCII code: ' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

3) Don't know much about it. event parameter is added to catch the fired event. It has all the property of the fired event like for 'keyup' it has 'charcode', keycode', 'key' etc.

Comment: Your answer worked,please answer my other two questions.

Comment: `keyup` triggers when you release the key so the counter won't update while you are pressing it.