# Made an AJAX script that is supposed to use GET to fetch data using my PHP file, not working

Tags: php, html, ajax

The code is supposed to fetch the query result and display it according to the number written in the text box, i tried (onkeydown and onkeyup) and both didn't work, i have no idea why it is not working and what is my mistake.

HTML code:

```
<script>
        function showRoom(rid) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getRoomAJAX.php?q="+rid, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <form> 
        <input type="text" name="rid" onkeydown="showRoom(this.value)">
    </form>

    <div id="txtHint">Room...</div>
```

getRoomAJAX.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$q = $_GET["q"];

$db = new Database();
$dbc = $db->getConnection();

if (!$dbc) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM indvProj_room WHERE rid = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//start creating the table HTML
if ($result) {
    echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellspacing = '2' cellpadding = '4' width='100%'>
          <tr>
          <th><b>Room ID</b></th>
          <th><b>Room Description</b></th>
          </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        echo "<tr>";;
        echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['adminRoomChoice'] = $row['rid'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['roomDesc'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">Sorry, cannot find the room, are you sure of the entered Room ID?</p>';
    echo '<p class = "error">' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '</p>';
}


?>
```

Comment: You have an error. [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) worked only for the old API. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Does `showRoom()` get called at all? Put a `console.log(rid);` inside `showRoom()` to see if that is getting called and whether the value is being passed in correctly.

If you can determine that it's getting into the `showRoom()`, then follow the code down and into PHP to see where it's failing. Echo some sample text at the top of the PHP file with `return;` right below it. That will tell you if the error is in the XMLHttpRequest code or somewhere in the PHP file.

Normally, I don't pass any variables/params with onkeydown type of events. Usually, I call a method like this without params and then retrieve the value based on the element's id. See this answer for more detail on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54040431/3103434