# equation from input field

Tags: javascript, math

I have three inputs which I want to add, When I place my first digit "5" console.log shows "0" the next input field I enter "2" this will console.log the first input field's digit "5" the third I enter "5" I see in console.log "7".

Why is this happening and how do I fix it please.

```
            <input id="roundOne" onkeypress="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">                
            <input id="roundTwo" onkeypress="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">                
            <input id="roundThree" onkeypress="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">
```

JavaScript.

```
             function mathScore(x, y, z){
                   return (x + y + z);
             }
             function obtainScoreOne() {    
                 //collect data
                 let n1, n2, n3, sum;
                    n1 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundOne').value);
                    n2 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundTwo').value);
                    n3 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundThree').value);        
                    sum = mathScore(n1, n2, n3);        
                 //Display result
                    console.log(sum);                     
              }
```

Comment: You don't really need to use Number for this. You can use parseInt(). Also you aren't checking if the values are empty first.

Comment: Instead of binding to keypress, bind to the input event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)

Comment: question was answered by Terry! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
function obtainScoreOne(n1, n2, n3) {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#roundOne').value);
  var n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#roundTwo').value);
  var n3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#roundThree').value);

  var sum;
  sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;                                          
}
```

```html
<input id="roundOne" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="number" value="0">            
<input id="roundTwo" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="number" value="0">          
<input id="roundThree" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="number" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress` is fired before the input value is set, try `onkeyup` instead:

```js
function mathScore(x, y, z) {
  return (x + y + z);
}

function obtainScoreOne() {
  //collect data
  let n1, n2, n3, sum;
  n1 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundOne').value);
  n2 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundTwo').value);
  n3 = Number(document.querySelector('#roundThree').value);
  sum = mathScore(n1, n2, n3);
  //Display result
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<input id="roundOne" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">
<input id="roundTwo" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">
<input id="roundThree" onkeyup="obtainScoreOne()" type="text">
```