# User input currency extra decimal

Tags: javascript

I have a user input box where users can type in an amount of USD currency. When the user types in a decimal to represent cents ex. 0.24 the value shows as 0.20 instead of .24 when the input is .244 or .240 it shows as the .24 cents. I would like the user to be able to type in just the .24 cents instead of having to enter in the extra decimal.

```js
var $partialText = $('#partialText');

$partialText.on('keypress', function() {
var $dark = parseFloat($partialText.val()); //Take the input value of partial input as a number

console.log($dark);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="partial" id="partialText" size="15" maxlength="6" />
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML and any CSS.

Comment: Please provide enough code in your snippet where someone can click Run code snippet and see what you're asking about. See [ask] and [mre] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are receiving in your `onKeyPress` handler is lagging behind the value you've entered. This should help: [How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input` event instead, which will also handle cases such as pasting text into the field.

```js
var $partialText = $('#partialText');

$partialText.on('input', function() {
var $dark = parseFloat($partialText.val()); //Take the input value of partial input as a number

console.log($dark);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="partial" id="partialText" size="15" maxlength="6" />
```

Comment: This example works.