# Input value not changing on keypress and keyup events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState('')

  const handleKeyPressUp = event => {
    const { value } = event.target

    setHeight(value)
  }

  return (
    <input
      value={height}
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPressUp}
      onKeyUp={handleKeyPressUp}
    />
  );
}
```

I've asked to use `keypress` instead of onChange to listen the input change. And I use both `onKeyPress` and `onKeyUp` because of `onKeyPress` is triggering right before the input value is changing([How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)), and also keypress will only be triggered for keys that produce a character value. i.e it won't be triggered on back space(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).

But when assigning the state `height` value to the input value, the input won't accept any input. Why the input value is not updated on typing text on the field?

Comment: Please use `onChange`, it will work fine. As opposed to a vanilla JS's onchange event, the event will fire during typing.

Comment: You're firing for both events, so `keyPress` fires and triggers a render, and your `keyUp` is lost. Keep in mind that react attaches `onChange` to the `input` event.

Answer (score 0):

Basically OnKeyPress events provide you the "key" which being typed. Using those key you can complete your task.

```
  const handleKeyPressUp = (event) => {
    const { key } = event;
    let value = height || "";
    if (key === "Backspace") {
      value = value.slice(0, value.length - 1);
    } else {
      value = value + key;
    }
    setHeight(value);
  };
```

check this link for working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-snow-mnrlf?file=/src/App.js:114-389

Note : Above method is kind of hack and need to handle some more corner cases, Using onChange listener is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

You can change like this

```
onChange={(event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setHeight(value)
}}
```

I guess this will resolve

Answer (score -1):

On this situation Prefer to use onChange instead of using onkeypress or onkeyup trigger.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).