# Unexpected error using an indexed element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I'm new to javascript and jquery, and stumbled upon an issue while writing a script.

My script is generated by php code which reads lines from a file, parses it and prints them out using arrays. js then validates form input, and outputs useful messages to the user.

I have successfully used js and jquery on `$('#id').blur` on various elements. However when I tried doing it on my indexed element, I came across this problem.

Code:

```
$('#NS_IN[0]').blur(function() {
        alert("Called");
        CopyNStoMain();     
    });
```

I noticed that this function would never get executed. I tried looking at the variables in console.

`typeof($('#NS_IN[0]'))` is an object; but `typeof($('#NS_IN[0]').val())` is Undefined.

In my html code, I have:

```
<input type="text" id="NS_IN[0]" value="" name="NS[0]">
```

What am I doing wrong? If the id `NS_IN[0]` is defined and `$(NS_IN[0])` refers to an object, shouldnt `$(NS_IN[0]).val()` exist and hold the value of the input box?

Comment: The jQuery selector sees the `[]` in a different way. Maybe if you try this way: `$("#NS_IN[" + "0" + "]")`.

Comment: I guess the selector should look like $("#NS_IN[0]").val()

Comment: Seems that the `[` is the culprint, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rePQm/ .

Comment: `typeof ( $("#NS_IN[0]").val() )` is undefined as well.

Comment: @Droidzone: yes, because the `[]` are used by jquery as attribute selectors, and must be escaped or circumvented by using a different type of selection for jquery (not `#id` if id has `[]` inside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the jquery selector characters.

```
$('#NS_IN\\[0\\]').blur(function() {
        alert("Called");
        CopyNStoMain();     
    });
```

Comment: I'm ignoring my own answer and up-voting yours. Perfect.

Comment: Also you could try wrapping your form in a `<div id="foo">` and use `$("#foo input")` as your selector. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more possible selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box)...I don't know how to tag your question as a duplicate.

```
//get
bla = $('#txt_name').val();
//set
$('#txt_name').val('bla');
```

Comment: No not exactly. I do know how to get the value of an input element. See how I included the check for `typeof($('#NS_IN[0]').val())`. My question is regarding the unexpected output, and the undefined variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry...do you want to check if the input is string or int or...?

Comment: I'm trying to use the value, but the square brackets are messing up the logic.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the `[]` works in a different way, like:

```
div[id^="player_"]
```

So, one of the solutions, is to select the items which ID starts with something:

```
$("input[id^=NS_IN]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use a different selector, as jquery uses the `[]` as an attribute selector itself. So use e.g. (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rePQm/1/ ):

> $('input').click(function() {   alert("clicked "  + this.id); });

an element selector that selects all input elements and adds the click handler to all of them. See the selectors section of the jquery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more possible selectors .