# Paste values into a Form

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm new to jquery.  I am trying to create a form that detects pasted values in a certain format.

For instance, I have the following:

Serial Number (20 digit number)
Part Number (####-HW)

If the user pastes in ####-HW it will go directly to the "Part Number" field.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Is the user supposed to paste one or the other into a general field and then it gets copied into one of these two types of fields? Or do you want a single field that just intelligently identifies the input type?

Comment: This could work.  A giant field for pasting data then goes to the correct field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this question getting the input: [Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box)

Once you have the value you can check it a bunch of ways, check the length to see if it is a serial number or check the last 2 digits of the array for a part number using just javascript.

If you want to get really complex you could look into regular expressions which would be able to pull specific patterns out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks PFM.  This looks helpful.  I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="serial"></input>
<input type="text" id="part"><input>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#serial').blur(function(){
   var serial = $('#serial').val();
   if(serial.indexOf("-HW")) {
    $('#part').val(serial);
   }
  }
 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you:

```
    $('.input').change(function() {

             if($(this).text().match('\d{20}-HW')) 
               {
               //enter your code here
                 }
    });
```

*not tested