# get value from textbox does not work

Tags: jquery

For my javascript code I tried the 2 alternative solutions in [Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box), answer 2 from RJD22, pls see code below. Option A works fine, but option B doesnt; the console shows 'undefined' when I enter a figure (or even some text).

Any idea why B does not work? I could use option A but I want to validate that the form field has been filled in, and from the val() description (http://api.jquery.com/val/) I cannot see what val() returns when no value has been filled in.

Thnx for any comments in advance.

html code:

```
</label> <input id="usage" type="text" name="usage">
```

javascript code:

```
this.usage = $("#usage").val(); //OPTION A:  WORKS

this.usage = $("#usage").attr("value"); //OPTION B: DOESNT WORK

console.log(this.usage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val()` returns `''` (empty string) when no value has been entered. You should use `val()` instead of `prop` or `attr`.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/V94Qq/)

Answer (score 0):

`attr` is used to get the actual attribute from the HTML. I think you should use `prop`.

You can read about the difference between `attr` and `prop` here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ways:

`var currentValue = $('#usage').prop("value");`

or

`var currentValue =$('#usage').val();`

In `attr('value')` you're specifically saying you're looking for the value of an attribute named value. It is preferable to use `val()` as this is jQuery's out of the box feature for extracting the value out of form elements.