# How to write on two input tag simultaneously by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two Input tag on my page with a button  :

```
   <input id="userName" style="direction: rtl" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
   <input id="txt" style="direction: rtl" type="text" value="" runat="server" />

   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" Style="display:none" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

i wrote a script which, [when] i click on Button1, put every thing on userName into txt:

```
   $('#Button1').click(function ()
        {

            $('#txt').value = $('#userName').value();

       });
```

but it doesn't work! what is the problem?

Comment: `$('#txt').val($('#userName').val());` - please go through the jQuery api before using it

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box

Comment: ^ I think think that one is a better one. @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Try this:

```
$('#Button1').click(function(){
   $('#txt').val($('#userName').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code where you can call `.val()` to read from `userName` and to put value to  `txt`.

```
$('#Button1').click(function ()
{
   $('#txt').val($('#userName').val());
});
```