# JQuery: How can I Make Two Text Inputs Effect Each Other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

```
Pixels <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="Pixels" value="Text 1"></input>
    <br />
    Percentage <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="Percentage" value="Text 1"></input>
```

Enter 10 in the first input, in the second input, how do I echo this *2 and for the other input /2 upon something being entered in the field.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This might be a good way to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box

Comment: What is var X? Percentage to what?

Comment: Var X is a variable which will be set at a later date @shaunakde as long as I can get both fields to display something upon the other being edited, I know how to do the maths involveed so I really should have just asked that question...

Comment: `input` elements are [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element), so they don't have an end tag. You can use `<input>` or `<input />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var X = 100;

var inp1 = document.getElementById('Pixels'),
    inp2 = document.getElementById('Percentage');

inp1.onchange = function() {
    var num = this.value = Math.max(Math.min(this.value, X), 0);
    inp2.value = num / X * 100;
};
inp2.onchange = function() {
    var num = this.value = Math.max(Math.min(this.value, 100), 0);
    inp1.value = num * X / 100;
};
```

Comment: I've never used the input type of number before, this just makes it even more better! Thank you!

Comment: @TimMarshall HTML5 improved forms a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTh2B/1/)**: for Percentage,

```
var X = 80;
$('#Pixels').keyup(function(){

    if(!isNaN(this.value)){
       $('#Percentage').val(parseInt(this.value)/X *100)
    }
});

$('#Percentage').keyup(function(){
    $('#Pixels').val(parseInt(this.value) * X/100);

});
```

---

- use `.val()` or `.value` to get value in the textbox.
- **[.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup)** or **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change)** are the events to get the values.
- There are more alternatives  **[jQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)**

Comment: This is perfect @shaunakde, I did edit to make more specific so it did not mean I was directly asking for my original to be done but you must of seen before the edit and made the perfect part for my website. Thank you :) +1