# How to find the contents of an <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to use JavaScript to find the contents of an input. I have tried this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("inputID");
 function myFunction() {
  if (x.value == 'Hi') {
     alert('Hello')
  } else {
    alert('Goodbye')
  }
 }
```

But it will not work. Please help!

Comment: You really shouldn't call a variable 1...

Comment: duplicate of [Get value in input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box)

Comment: @haylem the question you linked uses jQuery, OP probably does not

Comment: @izstas: you're right, I thought he was for some reason. My bad.

Comment: Can you show associated HTML?

Comment: @JeffersonRibeiro my apologies, I am just full of lies today. dropping the comment so as not to mislead anyone

Comment: @izstas: Answered accordingly then, and close vote retracted (though probably still a duplicate, but not of that one). Thanks for keeping me on my toes.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the errors in this question, I was half asleep when I asked it.

Answer (score 2):

### Corrected Version

```
var inputEl = document.getElementById("inputID");

unction myFunction() {
  if (inputEl.value === 'Hi') {
    alert("Hello");
  } else {
    alert("Goodbye");
  }
}
```

Which is pretty much what you had, except for few fixes and best practices:

- the variable name change (`inputEl` instead of `1` - see **Valid Identifiers** below)
- the strings in the `alert` statements (maybe they were variables, but we couldn't assert it from your snippet);
- the strict equality comparison;
- the missing semi-colons;

### Why It Didn't Work

It doesn't work because of the `1` variable name being invalid.

Then if it still doesn't work after that, then your HTML is wrong and the ID of your element isn't really `inputID`,

### Valid Identifiers

if you try this in Chrome's console (or another JS environment) to replicate your variable declaration:

```
var 1 = 'test';
```

You'll get a nice output similar to:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

So, just changing your variable name should be enough, if there aren't any other issues.

FYI, According to the Mozilla Developer Network, [valid identifiers in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) are:

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode
>   letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX
>   Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

For a less digestable version, the full spec for identifiers is in the [5.1 Edition of the ECMA-262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) in [section 7.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)

Comment: I didn't originally have variables called "1". I changed the names because they were very long and complicated.

Comment: @PrOdIgYCaRcAsS: then most likely your HTML didn't match your Javascript. Give us the full code and we can help further.