# jquery get input value from Div

Tags: jquery

the problem is more complicated with loops, but all I need is how to get value of:

> input id="product_addons_0_selections_2_id"

by accessing div with Id product_addons_0_selections_template2 as ex:

```
<div id="product_addons_0_selections_template2">    
   <input type="text" id="i_dont_need_this">
   <input type="text" id="product_addons_0_selections_2_id">
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: IDs must be unique, so just select it by the ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value in an input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Comment: if Id is not unique like in my case because if loop ?

Comment: In that case you need to change your loop. Your markup is invalid and that's not something that should be worked around. It's something that should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the contents of the input element with id `product_addons_0_selections_template2` by this statement:

```
var value = $('#product_addons_0_selections_2_id').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

This example shows you how to get the Value of a input:

```
var bla = $('#myInputID').val();
```

If you have a couple inside a container, you should iterate them:

```
$.each($('#product_addons_0_selections_template2').children(), function(){ 
    //Here you can ask for the id of the object: $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('#product_addons_0_selections_2_id').val()
```

Here is an example, type something in the second input and click, it should give you the value
https://jsfiddle.net/qqjkzuxk/