# Getting tables div content when pressed button into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get contents of each rows and write it in input but i can't do this work.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="a">abc</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="b">abcd</div>
            </td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="c">abcdf</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="d">abcde</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="magicButton">choose this row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.magicButton').click(function(){
        // insert text of div a into input
        // insert text of div b into input
        // ect
    });
});
```

Once you press the button it gets this values into following

```
<input type="text" name="whatver" div="fromValueA" readonly>
<input type="text" name="whatver" div="fromValueB" readonly>
<input type="text" name="whatver" div="fromValueC" readonly>
<input type="text" name="whatver" div="fromValueD" readonly>
```

How exactly can I get this to not just use the same A, B ,C from all buttons that are made

Best wishes, Mike

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. Do you want to add input to all `tr` when one button is clicked?

Comment: I want the contents of the row that I contains button into a readonly input

Comment: `this` is element event occurred on in any jQuery event handler. Use traverses up to row like `closest()` then `find()` within row. Note that you are duplicating ID's and id must be unique in page by definition. Not really clear what expected results are or where the readonly elements are

Comment: How does the closest to work? I heard of this never tested it in parctice could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery `replaceWith()` method to replacing `div` with `input`.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("table td > div").replaceWith(function(index, text){
        var id = "fromValue" + $(this).attr("id");
        return "<input id='" + id + "' value='" + text + "' />";
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="a">A</div>
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="b">B</div>
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="c">C</div>
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Change</button>
        </td>
     </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: That's really close how can I get change to give values from these tables to go into input that is only read where each ROW has a button

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box?rq=1 but where you have a button for each of them

Comment: @Mohammed https://jsfiddle.net/zsjmt1z1/1/ almost my good friend! how do I get that code to give the value into the input

Comment: @What is diffrence?

Comment: @MikeBroski If my answer is useful, please mark it.

Comment: Well your code does something I don't want to do the user should never ever be able to edit a table, I want him to click and he GETS THE VALUE from the tr...

Comment: @MikeBroski Use `readonly` attribute in input. See https://jsfiddle.net/zsjmt1z1/2/