# Why can I not get the value of a hidden item within a user asp.net user control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ascx user control and want to store the value of a TextBox on the usercontrol to a hidden item on the user control.  I then want to reference the hidden control in the C# code behind to do some validation.

I have this hidden item

```
<input type="Hidden" id="Hidden1" value="" clientidnode="Static" runat="server">
```

I want to set the value of this hidden item after the page loads and am trying to use this J Query script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
      var v1 = $("#<%=TxtCaseNumber.ClientID%>")
      $('#Hidden1').val(v1);
  });
```

I then use the C# code behind to check the value of the Hidden1 item using

```
string s = Hidden1.Value;
```

No value is being assigned?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `clientidmode` instead of `clientidnode`. :-)

Comment: shouldnt be like this? $("#<%=TxtCaseNumber.ClientID%>").val()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15903284/296861

Comment: Thanks to @ConnorsFan the problem has been resolved by changing to the clientmode.  Thanks for all the comments.  I had also forgot to get the value with the .val.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to get the actual value of the textbox

```
var v1 = $("#<%=TxtCaseNumber.ClientID%>").val();
```

Comment: I also had to correct a setting in the hidden item.  I had a typo and type ClientIdNode="static when it should have been ClientIdMode="static".  Once those 2 items were corrected it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the info above the problem was resolved by changing a setting in the hidden item to clientnode ="static" to clientidmode="Static" and by completing my code by getting the value of the text box by adding the forgotten .val.

Comment: People would be able to determine your resolution by you upvoting and marking an answer as accepted. You may also comment on the accepted answer to note the remark about the `clientmode`.