# Getting the value of input text which is created through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have done an option / list box in html form in which if i click 'Other' option, it will display an additional text field. I create the additional text field through javascript. The code is as below

```
<select name="how" class="subtitle" id="select" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">>
                          <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Please select</option>
                          <option>School</option>
                          <option>Consultant</option>
                          <option>WhatApp</option>
                          <option>Brochure / Poster</option>
                          <option>Internet</option>
                          <option>Other</option>  
                        </select></td>
```

Java Script is as below

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input id="othr" type="text" name="other" />';
```

It creates the text filed when 'Other' option is chosen. But how to get the value of other text field as the input tag is in the java script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value in an input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS:

```
var val = document.getElementById('othr').value
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/4669619

jQuery:

```
var val =  = $('#othr').val();
```

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903284/4669619