# Feeding a value from a textbox to a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable callled "myLocation".

I would like to take the value from my text box and feed it into 
"lat1" which is inside the variable "myLocation".

I have tried using the jQuery `$().attr('value')` function but it does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="input1">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input1').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            element1 = $('#input1').attr('value');

            var myLocation = {
                lat1: 2, // I wold like to feed data here from the textbox
                         // I tried element1 = $('#input1').attr('value'); but it does
                            not seem to work
                lng2: -56
            };
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't just drop JavaScript code in there, you need to put it in a `<script>` tag. You need `lat1: Number($('#input1').val()),`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value in an input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Comment: Works great Chris G.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's $('#input1').val() or $(this).val() within your function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input1').keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
      element1 = $(this).val();
      console.log("Element 1: ", element1);    
        
      var myLocation = {
        lat1: $(this).val(), 
        lng2: -56
      };
      
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "input1">
```

Comment: `$(this)` will be better than `$("#input1")` as it won't re-fetch it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
element1 = $('#input1').attr('value');
```

to

```
element1 = $(this).val();  // 'this' refers to the input element itself, benefit is that it wont refetch; val() will get the value
```

---

Read up: [`.attr()` | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

---

**Working code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#input1').keypress(function(event) {
    
    if (event.which == 13) {

      var element1 = $('#input1').val();  // make sure to initialize using "var" or else element1 will be a global variable!
      
      var myLocation = {
        lat1: element1,
        lng2: -56
      };
      
      console.log('myLocation', myLocation); // verify it in your log!
    };
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1">
```