# Using jQuery to show/hide an element if some value is found in document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide an element if some specific value of input is not found on the site.
I can hide an element by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#someid").hide();
});
```

But how to show it, if the value is found? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#someid").hide();
$("input[value$='somevaluetobefound']").ready(function() {
    $("#someid").show();
});
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Use an `if` statement, not `ready`.  2. Listen on an event.  Your current setup checks the value on document ready, then never again.

Comment: Could you look at my answer what am I doing wrong? @jmargolisvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not fully understood what you where trying to acomplish:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 if (!$('input[value="somevaluetobefound"]'))
  $("#someid").hide();

  $(':input').on('keyup', function(){       
   if ($(this).val() == 'somevaluetobefound')  
    {
      $("#someid").show();
    } else {
         $("#someid").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I have updated the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gatrk7rs/6/)

EDIT: Based on new info provided by OP

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($(':radio[value="somevaluetobefound"]').length !== 0)
   $("#someid").show();
  else 
   $("#someid").hide();
});
```

Sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n7nkgbpx/2/)

Comment: How should I define here ` input[value$='somevaluetobefound'] `?

Comment: @katt if you are looking for a specific value it should be: `if ($("#someid").val() == 'somevaluetobefound')`

Comment: could you look at my answer if I do everything right?

Comment: @katt I have updated my answer so it uses the selector the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that code shows a div even if `<input value=` is changed :(

Comment: Sorry, I had not fully understood what you where trying to acomplish @katt

Comment: Sadly, still, if I will change the value of input from  `somevaluetobefound` to anything other, the div is not being hided.

Comment: @katt did you check the [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/gatrk7rs/6/) code? If you change the value in the box the div is hidden and shown again when it matches the text again. In case that is not what you want, you should better explain what it is you need.

Comment: Oh, I didn't try that, it actually works :) However, it's not what I need :( My input is radio type, so the value is only an information about kind of input. What I need is to hide div if this `somevaluetobefound` value is not found.

Comment: You can see what I mean here https://jsfiddle.net/n7nkgbpx/ If first `input` would not be found the div shouldn't be shown. Is it doable by jQuery?

Comment: I have to start learning jQuery, because it's a really great tool to use on websites. Thank you again :)

Comment: Oh, i've get little scared, because it worked on my localhost, but didn't in public. Then I realised some problems with using $, so I changed them all to `jQuery` and now everything works :)

Comment: @kat glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#someid").hide();

$('#inputID').on('input', function() {
 if ( $('input').val() === 'test') {
    $("#someid").show();
 }
  else $("#someid").hide();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type 'test' to show DIV<br>
<input id="inputID" type="text">
<div id="someid">DIV</div>
```

Comment: the problem is, my input doesn't have an ID, it's a `value` string which I need to distinguish from another

Comment: Why can't your input have an id? In most cases it is necessary to have an id, if not for javascript but for CSS too.

Comment: it's old oscommerce shop engine

Comment: If it's an old oscommerce shop engine it probably is aspx, correct? And I highly doubt there isn't an ID tag on it, if there is all you have to do in your html markup is grab the ID like so:
`$("#<%=inputID.ClientID%>")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[value=somevaluetobefound]").closest('#someid').hide();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#someid").hide();

 if($("#someid").val() !=''){
     $("#someid").show();
 }
});
```

Comment: How should I define here ` input[value$='somevaluetobefound'] `?

Answer (score 0):

Improvising on @Arkej's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#someDiv").hide();

    $(':input').on('input', function() {
        if ( $('input').val() === 'somevalue') {
             $("#someDiv").show();
           }
        else $("#someDiv").hide();
         });
    });
```

Here I am using `:input` to find all input boxes on the page. Since you need to either have an ID the input field you want or just have all input text boxes be used to show or hide your div depending on what the value you are looking for.

Also refer to this for guidance on getting val from inputs:
[Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box#comment68474837_15903284)

Cheers