# How do I show my form in a jQuery alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having this problem where I can't seem to figure out how to show my (filled in) form in a jquery alert. Under my code is a standard form in HTML nothing wrong there all `id`'s are named what you can see in the `.val()`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val();
      console.log(name);
      $('#form').submit(function() {
        $('#progress').show();
        alert (" Formulier: " + $("#form input").val(name, email, number, comment));
      });
    });
</script>
<style>
    #progress {
      display: none;
      color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You are not reading the input values correctly. Possible duplicate of [Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box). And FYI, there is no such thing as a _"jQuery alert"_.

Comment: `$("#form input").val(name, email, number, comment)` - what is that supposed to achieve? Did you find such a syntax for .val() documented anywhere ... or are you just inventing your own here?

Comment: I really don't know I knew that part was wrong but still it's not working I'm new to jquery

Comment: It's not really clear from that line of code what you're even *trying* to do.  Are you just trying to show a single alert box with all of the values which are currently in the form?  Are you able to do this with *one* value, and try to expand from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all form values with [serialize()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp) method.

```
alert (" Formulier: " + $("#form input").serialize());
```