# Get dynamic value to input type"text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turnjs

I am trying to customize [TurnJS](http://turnjs.com/catalog)  with some special effects. I need to show current page number while flip each page into a `<input type="text" id="pageNumber" value="">` field.

The value should get with this function *(added alert for test)*:

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turned", function(event, page, view) {
  alert("Page: "+$("#flipbook").turn("view")[0] +$("#flipbook").turn("view")[1] );
});
```

How can I get this value to the `<input>` field?

Can I use this: [Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4088467/6191987) ?

Comment: so set the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.val()` method to fill the input-tag.

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turned", function(event, page, view) {
  $('#pageNumber').val(page);
});
```

See [jQuery .val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)