# How to have the input value appear?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I am new to coding and I have to do this an assignment for school, I am just a little bit stuck on this part of the assignment. I need to be able to make it that when someone enters their name into the input box the name will then appear on the next page. How would I be able to do that? My code is here if you need or want to look at it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

 

    <style>

        body {

            text-align: center;

        }

 

        table,

        th,

        td {

            border: 0px solid white;

            border-collapse: collapse;

            width: 45%;

            height: 55px;

            text-align: center;

            vertical-align: center;

            table-layout: fixed;

        }

 

        table.center {

            margin-left: auto;

            margin-right: auto;

        }

 

        .Tableheader {

            border: 0px solid white

        }

 

        .TableCell {

            background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);

            border: 2px solid black;

        }

 

        .button {

            padding: 5px;

            background-color: #dcdcdc;

            border: 1px solid #666;

            color: #000;

            margin-top: 10px;

        }

 

        button:hover {

            color: yellow;

        }

 

        .TableCell:hover {

            background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);

        }

        body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
    </style>

</head>

 

</body>
<div id="MainMenu">
    <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
        <ul>
    <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
    <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
    <li><input  type='text' name ='text1'/></li>
    <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

 <div id="Table">
<h2>Hurkles</h2>
<p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
<table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

        </tr>
        

    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>

 

<script>
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";

function Start(){
    Table.style.display = "block"
    MainMenu.style.display = "none"
    
    
}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});






   

     function tableText(col){
        if (typeof event!=='undefined')
            el=event.srcElement
            for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
                el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor=''
            el.style.backgroundColor=col
    }
    
    
    let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex-1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
    document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => { 
        tableText('green');
    }
    
    function hideAll(){
    Table.style.display = "none"
    MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}


function gameReset(){

}

function required(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
    if(empt == ""){
        alert("Please input your name");
    }
        else{
            Start()
        }
        
    
}

    

</script>

 

</html>

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code there is an error occurring when running the code.
When you try to get `document.getElementById('text1')`
You are searching the element by ID

Add a id attribute to your input tag

Change this line :

```
<li><input  type='text' name ='text1'/></li>

<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
```

To:

```
<li><input  type='text' name ='text1' id='text1'/></li>

<li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
```

You can check the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

 

    <style>

        body {

            text-align: center;

        }

 

        table,

        th,

        td {

            border: 0px solid white;

            border-collapse: collapse;

            width: 45%;

            height: 55px;

            text-align: center;

            vertical-align: center;

            table-layout: fixed;

        }

 

        table.center {

            margin-left: auto;

            margin-right: auto;

        }

 

        .Tableheader {

            border: 0px solid white

        }

 

        .TableCell {

            background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);

            border: 2px solid black;

        }

 

        .button {

            padding: 5px;

            background-color: #dcdcdc;

            border: 1px solid #666;

            color: #000;

            margin-top: 10px;

        }

 

        button:hover {

            color: yellow;

        }

 

        .TableCell:hover {

            background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);

        }

        body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
    </style>

</head>

 

</body>
<div id="MainMenu">
    <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
        <ul>
    <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
    <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
    <li><input  type='text' name ='text1' id='text1'/></li>
    <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

 <div id="Table">
<div id='playerName'></div>
<h2>Hurkles</h2>
<p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
<table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

        </tr>
        

    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>

 

<script>
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';

function Start(){
    Table.style.display = "block"
    MainMenu.style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
    
}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});






   

     function tableText(col){
        if (typeof event!=='undefined')
            el=event.srcElement
            for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
                el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor=''
            el.style.backgroundColor=col
    }
    
    
    let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex-1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
    document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => { 
        tableText('green');
    }
    
    function hideAll(){
    Table.style.display = "none"
    MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}


function gameReset(){

}

function required(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
    if(empt == ""){
        alert("Please input your name");
    }
        else{
            name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
            Start()
        }
        
    
}

    

</script>

 

</html>

</script>
```

The name will appear on the next page at the top and change the CSS according to you
Copy this snippet and use it

Hope it helps you!